# unity Drag and drop Function image change

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, user-interface, drag, drop

//  I want to change the image to another image on the on-drop function, I am using the Simple card script.

// public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

```
 public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
 Vector3 startPosition;
 Transform startParent;
 #region IBeginDragHandler implementation
 public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
      itemIsDragged = gameObject;
        StartPos = transform.position;
        Debug.Log("On Begin Drag");
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
 }
 #endregion
 #region IDragHandler implementation
 public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
 }
 #endregion
 #region IEndDragHandler implementation
 public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
    
       
        canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
         itemIsDragged = null;
        transform.position = StartPos;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;

 }
 #endregion
```

//  this script goes to placeholders

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler {

```
 public GameObject item
 {
     get
     {
         if(transform.childCount > 0)
         {
             return transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
         }
         else
         {
             return null;
         }
     }
 }
 #region IDropHandler implementation
 public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     if(!item)
     {
         transform.SetParent(transform);
     }
 }
 #endregion
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I want to replace the image with another image but Ondrop() function, doesn't give access 2nd time to replace the image and doesn't allow us to make another child

Comment: in your slot class, OnDrop, sets the parent of current object equal to current object.